# Multiple layer animations, how to pause only one of them

Tags: ios, core-animation

I added multiple animations in one layer, now I want to pause one of them, other animations can still run, how to do it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

CALayer has method to get animation by a key

```
func animation(forKey key: String) -> CAAnimation?
```